# Google Maps not working in jQuery easytabs

Tags: jquery, html, css, google-maps

when you click the contact tab, it is load the gmaps but not properly.(only the left corner of the map) really interesting... any ideas?

[here is the jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kL7rv/1/)

structure of my html code:

```
        <div id="menu-container" class="section group">
        <div id="menuu" class="col span_8_of_12">
            <!-- Navigation Bar -->
            <div class="menu">
                <ul class='tabs'>
                    <li class='tab-biography'><a href="#aboutme">About Me</a></li>
                    <li class='tab-portfolio'><a href="#portfolio">Portfolio</a></li>
                    <li class='tab-photos'><a href="#photos">Photos</a></li>
                    <li class='tab-contact'><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="social-icons" class="col span_4_of_12">
            <!-- Social Icons -->
            <ul class="social-icons">
                <li><a href="#"><img src "img/icons/rss.png" g" alt=""/></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src "img/icons/twitter.png" g" alt=""/></a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><img src "img/icons/facebook.png" g" alt=""/></a></li>
            </ul>
            <!-- /Social Icons -->
        </div>
        <!-- /Navigation Bar -->
    </div>
```

gmaps:

```
function initialize() {
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(41.00527, 28.97696);
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 16,
        center: myLatlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    }
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatlng,
        map: map,
    });
}

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: try setting a default width to your map-canvas div say 890px...

Comment: @KarthikGanesan still same.

Comment: 1. You have no `map-canvas` in your HTML. 2. What is the `g"` in your HTML? That is not valid.  3. What external scripts are required? (a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7ukVe/) that shows the problem would be helpful...)

Comment: @geocodezip i am so sorry. i fix the format you can see here: http://jsfiddle.net/kL7rv/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to trigger the map `resize` event after the tab containing the map is made visible.  Looking at [the documentation](http://os.alfajango.com/easytabs/), there is an event hook for that purpose:

`easytabs:after | Fires after a tab has been selected (and after the panel is completely finished transitioning in).     | [event, $clicked, $targetPanel, settings]`

```
$('#content').bind('easytabs:after', function() {
   google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');     
});
```

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/upjV6/1/)